# c# . getting unreachable code error in switch statement

Tags: c#

im getting unreachable code detected error in below code. 
could anybudy pls guide on this issue , wil get bundle of thanks from bottom of my heart

```
public decimal SetDiscountLevel()
{
  int range= spentAmount/500;    
  switch(range)
  { 
    case 0: 
       return 0;
       break;
    case 1:
       return 0.05m;
       break;
    case 2:
       return 0.06m;
       break;
    case 3:
       return 0.08m;
       break;
    default:
       return 0.1m;
       break;

  }      
}
```

Comment: It's not an error but a warning, as you have `return xxx;` on each case the `break;` after them are unreachable, just remove these.

Comment: No need for the breaks.

Comment: Why the tag spam?

Answer (score 3):

Remove **break;** after **return;** keyword because if you use **return;** in case then **break;** will not be reached because you just stopped execution of loop with **return;** keyword.

See code below

```
    public decimal SetDiscountLevel()
{
   int range= spentAmount/500;    
   switch(range)
     { 
        case 0: 
           return 0;
        case 1:
           return 0.05m;
        case 2:
           return 0.06m;
        case 3:
           return 0.08m;
        default:
           return 0.1m;

     }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear

Comment: There's no loop here.

Answer (score 3):

In each case you are immediately returning a value, meaning that the following break will never be executed.

Just do the following

```
public decimal SetDiscountLevel()
{
   int range= spentAmount/500;    
   switch(range)
     { 
        case 0: 
           return 0;
        case 1:
           return 0.05m;
        case 2:
           return 0.06m;
        case 3:
           return 0.08m;
        default:
           return 0.1m;
     }      
}
```